# Unable to share in linked in, it shows error : Plugin com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension interrupted in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using UIActivityViewController to share text and link to Linkedin.
Dialog view appears and in after that immediately disappears with these 2 errors in log :

plugin com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension interrupted

plugin com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension invalidated

Comment: Please supply some code. What have you done so far?